# Python keeps outputting zero for code that is supposed to determine how many times a substring occurs in a string

Tags: python

I am just looking for hints, but the question asks me to identify how many times 'bob' occurs in a string of letters

```
s = 'bgobobjboyjgobobabog'

bob = 0

for i in s[0:-2]:

     i = s.find(i)

     if s[i] == 'b' and s[i+1] == 'o' and s[i + 2] == 'b':

        bob += 1


print(bob)
```

problem is my code keeps either only counting 'b' and not 'bob', or counting nothing at all and outputting zero, he

Comment: is `bobob` 2 bobs or 1 bob?

Comment: @MYGz - I'm gonna go ahead and rehammer that.